# Sonic boom on atomic particles

Tags: atomic-physics, acoustics, shock-waves

we know that something travelling faster than the speed of sound creates a continuous sonic boom because the air cant get of its way fast enough  but if we consider smaller particles which can travel much faster they cannot create a sonic boom because they are not ;arge enough and do not interact with the air particles. What is the minimum mass or size at which a particle can bend air particles and create the loud noise

Comment: What non-neutrino particles are small enough not to collide with other atmospheric molecules?  The typical mean free path at sea level is on the order of a micron for any single atom or molecule.  None of them move too fast because they collide and eventually form the standard Maxwell-Boltzmann velocity distribution.  If you try to give a particle too much energy, it will either ionize or split atoms.